# How to combine the sidewaystable environment with a long table?

Tags: rotating, landscape, threeparttable, threeparttablex, sidewaystable

I have a big landscape oriented table in my document. For this I'm using the `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` from `rotating` package. However, when I create a landscape oriented table, with 2 or more pages, the `sidewaystable` environment does not work correctly. I was reading and founded tht using the `landscape` environment from de `pdflscape` package is a good idea (I tested and it works), however the `landscape` environment does not create a float like `sidewaystable` does. Someone can help me? I really want to use `sidewaystable` instead `landscape`

MWE with `sidewaystable`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}c}
\caption{Caption}\\%
\midrule
\textbf{Head 1}&%
\textbf{Head 2}&%
\textbf{Head 3}&%
\textbf{Head 4}&%
\textbf{\makecell{Head 5.1\\Head 5.2}}\\%
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable~--~continued from previous page}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Head 1}&%
\textbf{Head 2}&%
\textbf{Head 3}&%
\textbf{Head 4}&%
\textbf{\makecell{Head 5.1\\Head 5.2}}\\%
\midrule
\endhead
%
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}%
{Continued on next page...}
\endfoot
%
\midrule
\endlastfoot
%
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

MWE with `landscape`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}c}
\caption{Caption}\\%
\midrule
\textbf{Head 1}&%
\textbf{Head 2}&%
\textbf{Head 3}&%
\textbf{Head 4}&%
\textbf{\makecell{Head 5.1\\Head 5.2}}\\%
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable~--~continued from previous page}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Head 1}&%
\textbf{Head 2}&%
\textbf{Head 3}&%
\textbf{Head 4}&%
\textbf{\makecell{Head 5.1\\Head 5.2}}\\%
\midrule
\endhead
%
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}%
{Continued on next page...}
\endfoot
%
\midrule
\endlastfoot
%
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\
&\blindtext&&\blindtext& \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: for long table in landscape orientation you need to use package `lscape` or `pdflscape`, sideways˙` doesn't support tables longer than one page.

Comment: And `longtable`s never float.